# AWS S3: Lifecycle rules for permanently deleting delete markers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I currently have versioning set up and thus a delete results to a delete marker and not to a permanent delete, which is what I like.

Is there a lifecycle rule that I can add so that after 30 days since the delete markers were created, they are permanently deleted?

I only want to do this for delete markers, not for expiring anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-configuration-examples.html#lifecycle-config-conceptual-ex7):

```
 <LifecycleConfiguration>
    <Rule>
        ...
        <NoncurrentVersionExpiration>     
            <NoncurrentDays>30</NoncurrentDays>    
        </NoncurrentVersionExpiration>
    </Rule>
 </LifecycleConfiguration>
```

Important thing to note is:

> A delete marker with zero noncurrent versions is referred to as an
> expired object delete marker.

Comment: I am confused by the docs from AWS. Does this config still permanently delete files that have a delete marker even when there are no files left in the bucket that are not marked for delete? The docs sound like they make the latest file marked for delete, current again, removing the marker automatically after the expiration days in this case?

Comment: A file is considered expired, when there are no active versions. This happens as soon as the last version is deleted. A delete marker is created. This delete marker is permanently removed after 30 days.

Comment: And by "delete marker is permanently removed", does that mean the file is permanently deleted?

Comment: Yes, this means that the file is gone for good and can't be undeleted.

Comment: What's the Console UI version of this? Doesn't seem neither "Expire current versions of objects" nor "Permanently delete noncurrent versions of objects". Should be like "Expire noncurrent version of objects" :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is the rule configuration using the Management Console:

[image: Management Console screenshot]